# Slider with less than 4 steps not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a slider that works perfectly when there are 4 steps to slide.

However, reducing the steps to 2 or 3 makes it clunky. Why?

As you can see in the image, the second slider doesn't fill correctly when last step (4K) is selected. why?

[image]

**Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/KKMrXQw

**Code:**

```
<div class="__range __range-step __range-step-popup">
    <input value="1" type="range" max="4" min="1" step="1" list="ticks2">
    <datalist id="ticks2">
        <option value="1">Very bad</option>
        <option value="2">Bad</option>
        <option value="3">Good</option>
        <option value="4">Excellent</option>
    </datalist>
    <output class="__range-output-square"></output>
</div>





<div class="__range __range-step __range-step-popup">
    <input value="1" type="range" max="4" min="1" step="1" list="ticks2">
    <datalist id="ticks2">
        <option value="1">1080p</option>
        <option value="2">2K</option>
        <option value="3">4K</option>
    </datalist>
    <output class="__range-output-square"></output>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input max is set to 4 and should be set to 3. [working example](https://codepen.io/xdumaine/pen/gOMQVBG).

```html
...
<input value="1" type="range" max="3" min="1" step="1" list="ticks2">
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just correct the mistake, max must be set to 3 if there is max 3 steps.

```
<input value="1" type="range" max="3" min="1" step="1" list="ticks2">
```